# SSRS parameter value max and min value in same field

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I am trying to create a parameter that would allow the user to select one or many of three values.
0-99,
99-100 &
200+

Is this possible using just one parameter? If so what would the SQL syntax need to be to filter the dataset and what syntax would need to be in the parameter values?

I know I can use the BETWEEN function with two parameters for max and min, but would like to have it in one

I thought I could assign values to each parameter option then check for the sum of these, for example 0-99 has a value of 1, 99-100 has a value of 5 and 200+ has a value of 10. Then use a CASE or IF statement to check these values and run the appropriate SQL statement to pick all or any combination of the numbers. But it seems the SSRS query designer does not like IF or CASE to see the results of a parameter either using the @Parameter or the Parameters!Name.Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a parameter in your ssrs like this

@range

```
Display | Value
0-99 | 1
100 - 199 | 2
200+ | 3
```

And something like this in your SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.table a
WHERE ((@range = 1 AND a.value BETWEEN 0 AND 99)
OR (@range = 2 AND a.value BETWEEN 100 AND 199)
OR (@range = 3 AND a.value >= 200))
```

To do a combination of the 3 you will need to use three parameters

```
@range1
@range2
@range3
```

Then the following in your SQL

```
WHERE ((@range1 = 1 AND a.value BETWEEN 0 AND 99)
OR (@range2 = 1 AND a.value BETWEEN 100 AND 199)
OR (@range3 = 1 AND a.value >= 200))
```

Comment: Great....thanks. Just one small problem, this works fine if I only want to select one of the three possibilities, how do I code this so the user can select one or any combination of the three?

Comment: @FredTheDog - please see the edit above, sorry about the late reply on hols! Hope it still helps. Please vote up if it has :-)

Comment: Thanks SQL_Lemming, I managed to figure out some complex method using hidden parameters with default values which I can then query to get any combination. Your solution certainly works, but I wanted to keep the choices in one parameter.

Comment: I can't Vote Up as am new to this forum and don't yet have the "reputation" points.....Sorry :(